# Creating MongoDB through Helm with Gitlab fails

Tags: mongodb, gitlab, kubernetes-helm

I followed the instructions here to create a Mongo instance using `helm`. This requires some adaptation as it's being created through gitlab with gitlab-ci.
Unfortunately, the part about `values.yaml` gets skimmed over and I haven't found complete examples for mongo through helm. [Many of the examples also seemed deprecated as well.]
Being unsure how to address the issue, using this as a `values.yaml` file:

```
global:
  mongodb:
    DBName: 'example'
    mongodbUsername: "user"
    mongodbPassword: "password"
    mongodbDatabase: "database"
    mongodbrootPassword: "password"
    auth.rootPassword: "password"
```

The following error is returned:

```
'auth.rootPassword' must not be empty, please add '--set auth.rootPassword=$MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD' to the command. To get the current value:
        export MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$(kubectl get secret --namespace angular-23641052-review-86-sh-mousur review-86-sh-mousur-mongodb -o jsonpath="{.data.mongodb-root-password}" | base64 --decode)
```

Given that I'm only using `helm` as called by gitlab-ci, I am unsure on how to implement the `set` or otherwise set the root password.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could tell, I thought setting variables in `env` in values.yaml had solved the problem:

```
env:          
 - name: "auth.rootPassword"
   value: "password"
```

The problem went away - but has returned.

Gitlab is making a move towards using `.gitlab/auto-deploy-values.yaml`.
I created a local version of autodeploy.sh and added the value auth.rootPassword="password" to auto-deploy-value.yaml and the value seems to work. cf. `[Gitlab's documentation][1]`